# find in list almost equal elements, make new list correspond to position or some list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elements called `q` and wish to compute Total Multiplicity of each element, and put these values in the list `tm`.

I need to search for almost equal elements, then list them as a new list with each element's position.

This new list would contain several lists, because there are many elements that are equal relative to each other.

**Here is an example:**

q list from 0 to 200 correspond to certain values in tm length 201 same as q.

```
q={0,....,200};
tm={1,3,3,7,3,1,7,8,4}

lst of 3 elements {q,tm}={{1,3},{2,3},{4,3}}

lst1 of 1 elements {q,tm}={{0,1},{5,1}}
```

and so on...

**Here is my code: Look at the last line where `tm` is calculated.**

```
n = 200; "Whole"
q = 200; "Whole"
na = 1; "System"
nb = 199; "Reservoir"


m[n_, q_] := N[(q + n - 1)!/(q!*(n - 1)!)];

qa = Table[q[j], {j, 0, q}]; 
qb = Reverse[Table[q[j], {j, 0, q}]]; 

qa1 = qa[[All,1]]; 
qb1 = qb[[All,1]]; 

"System Multiplicity"
ma = m[na, qa1]; 

"Reservoir Multiplicity"
mb = m[nb, qb1]; 

"Total Multiplicity"
tm = ma*mb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tm = {1, 3, 3, 7, 3, 1, 7, 8, 4};
A = GroupBy[Transpose[{Range[Length[tm]] - 1, tm}], Last]
```

> <|1 -> {{0, 1}, {5, 1}}, 3 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}}, 7 -> {{3, 7}, {6, 7}}, 8 -> {{7, 8}}, 4 -> {{8, 4}}|>

```
Values[A]
```

> {{{0, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 7}, {6, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{8, 4}}}

```
Lookup[A, 1]
```

> {{0, 1}, {5, 1}}

```
Lookup[A, 3]
```

> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}}

You say that you want to group "almost equal" elements. I'm not quite sure how you mean this, and propose to use `Round`ing of the grouping key. For example, grouping by rounding the elements to integer multiples of 3:

```
A = GroupBy[Transpose[{Range[Length[tm]] - 1, tm}], Round[Last[#], 3] &]
```

> <|0 -> {{0, 1}, {5, 1}}, 3 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {8, 4}}, 6 -> {{3, 7}, {6, 7}}, 9 -> {{7, 8}}|>

Comment: how do i make list of them separately the new equal list

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `Association`s: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html

Comment: sir how can i ListPlot them !?

Comment: cool i did it by Normal